# How do I subract using one single statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql

How can I subtract the result of this query:

```
SELECT COUNT(Laptops) FROM (SELECT aaaUser.FIRST_NAME AS User,COUNT(workstation.WORKSTATIONNAME) AS Laptops FROM SystemInfo workstation 
LEFT JOIN Resources resource ON workstation.WORKSTATIONID=resource.RESOURCEID 
LEFT JOIN ResourceOwner rOwner ON resource.RESOURCEID=rOwner.RESOURCEID 
LEFT JOIN ResourceAssociation rToAsset ON rOwner.RESOURCEOWNERID=rToAsset.RESOURCEOWNERID 
LEFT JOIN SDUser sdUser ON rOwner.USERID=sdUser.USERID 
LEFT JOIN AaaUser aaaUser ON sdUser.USERID=aaaUser.USER_ID WHERE ( aaaUser.FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL)  AND ISSERVER=0 
GROUP BY "User"
HAVING Laptops > 1
ORDER BY Laptops DESC) AS e
```

from this one:

```
SELECT SUM(Laptops) FROM (SELECT aaaUser.FIRST_NAME AS User,COUNT(workstation.WORKSTATIONNAME) AS Laptops FROM SystemInfo workstation 
LEFT JOIN Resources resource ON workstation.WORKSTATIONID=resource.RESOURCEID 
LEFT JOIN ResourceOwner rOwner ON resource.RESOURCEID=rOwner.RESOURCEID 
LEFT JOIN ResourceAssociation rToAsset ON rOwner.RESOURCEOWNERID=rToAsset.RESOURCEOWNERID 
LEFT JOIN SDUser sdUser ON rOwner.USERID=sdUser.USERID 
LEFT JOIN AaaUser aaaUser ON sdUser.USERID=aaaUser.USER_ID WHERE ( aaaUser.FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL)  AND ISSERVER=0 
GROUP BY "User"
HAVING Laptops > 1
ORDER BY Laptops DESC) AS e
```

while only using a single query?

I am trying to create a report in a product that does not support running multiple queries - so temp tables are not an option.

Thanks in advance,

Ben

Comment: -1: Please be clearer. What is your definition of "subtract" in this sense? Are we talking set difference? Per row value subtraction? Please provide example input and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUM(Laptops) - COUNT(Laptops)
from ...
```

since your aggregate functions will be the last thing applied to the result of your `GROUP`.

Answer (score 4):

Unless I'm missing something, can't you just do this?

```
SELECT SUM(Laptops) - COUNT(Laptops)
FROM (SELECT aaaUser.FIRST_NAME AS User,COUNT(workstation.WORKSTATIONNAME) AS Laptops FROM SystemInfo workstation 
LEFT JOIN Resources resource ON workstation.WORKSTATIONID=resource.RESOURCEID 
LEFT JOIN ResourceOwner rOwner ON resource.RESOURCEID=rOwner.RESOURCEID 
LEFT JOIN ResourceAssociation rToAsset ON rOwner.RESOURCEOWNERID=rToAsset.RESOURCEOWNERID 
LEFT JOIN SDUser sdUser ON rOwner.USERID=sdUser.USERID 
LEFT JOIN AaaUser aaaUser ON sdUser.USERID=aaaUser.USER_ID WHERE ( aaaUser.FIRST_NAME IS NOT NULL)  AND ISSERVER=0 
GROUP BY "User"
HAVING Laptops > 1
ORDER BY Laptops DESC) AS e
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (SELECT query 1 ... ...) - (SELECT query 2 ... ...) AS 'value';
```